# Last Posukim in the Torah

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, writing-printing, pentateuch-chumash

Who wrote the last eight Pesukim of the Torah?

Comment: I believe Ibn Ezra says Y'hoshu'a wrote the last 12 - i.e. from when Moshe went up the mountain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either Moshe or Yehoshua, according to a machlokes in Baba Basra 15a. the Chasam Sofer puts it as Yehoshua:
http://parsha.blogspot.com/2010/09/chasam-sofer-on-last-eight-pesukim-or.html

Comment: This is phrased poorly. Chasam Sofer does not necessarily "put it" either way. He simply quotes the opinion that Yehoshua wrote the last 8 pesukim, and asks that according to that opinion, perhaps the previous 4 pesukim were also written by Yehoshua. He has no question according to the other opinion and therefore does not cite it.
Abarbanel, though, clearly favors the opinion that Moshe wrote the Torah in its entirety.

Answer (score 3):

According to Rashi, Rav Yehuda holds it was written by Yehoshua. There are others that hold Moshe wrote it with his tears.

Comment: The _g'mara_ says "with tears", if I'm not mistaken. While that is most easily read as "with tears in his eyes", I've heard another interpretation (which I don't recall in full, so won't supply).

Comment: @msh210, the other interpretation you heard was probably that of the Gra, who instead of reading "b'demma" (with tears) in the gemara, reads "b'dimua" (jumbled up), and then Yehoshua rearranged the letters.

Comment: @jake: I meant the explanation of the _Sifse Chachamim_ at the end of "_V'zos Hab'racha_" (or, presumably, whomever he's quoting), that the words were written with tears instead of ink.